# AOSP not loading due to one line of code

Tags: exception, android-service, android-source, android-service-binding

So I had created a new Service and added to AOSP. The service runs fine when being called from apps. But I want to call few methods of the service from inside the framework code (Source/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java).

Is there a special way I need to call create the instance for the service in order for it to be used inside the frameworks.

```
 ITestService om = ITestService.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("Test"));
```

The above is the way I make an instance to the service inside the PackageParser.java, (the same worked fine when I tried to access it from an app).

The below is the snippet of errors I got from logcat:

```
***********************************************
F/SystemServer(  500): BOOT FAILURE starting Input Manager Service
F/SystemServer(  500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider
F/SystemServer(  500):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4201)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at android.app.ActivityThread.getProvider(ActivityThread.java:4010)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4026)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1612)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:948)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getString(Settings.java:701)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getString(Settings.java:2207)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.buildInputMethodListLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1966)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.(InputMethodManagerService.java:556)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:273)
F/SystemServer(  500): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider
F/SystemServer(  500):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
F/SystemServer(  500):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4186)
F/SystemServer(  500):  ... 9 more
I/SystemServer(  500): Accessibility Manager
W/SystemServer(  500): ***********************************************
F/SystemServer(  500): BOOT FAILURE making display ready
```

Just before this error I was able to see the success log message saying my service has been started.

I just commented one line which makes instance to my service in PackageParser.java, and the code seemed to work creating the system.img

Any inputs on this problem could help me a lot.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because of the dex opt signature mismatch for SettingsProvider.apk For testing purposes I was able to get around this issue by disabling this check achieved by setting the below env variables:

export WITH_DEXPREOPT=false

export DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true

Courtesy: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/vJCkg8Yq9Ic/mgev8ODDia4J

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your service you use Settings provider. But this provider is not yet started, when you call it. If this is the case then you need to add to your service an additional method, for instance, `setUp()`, where you need to set up connection with your PackageParser when Settings provider is already loaded.